# Is it possible to ask Mathematica to give the maximum value of a function over a specific domain?

Tags: numerics, numerical-value, maximum

I have a function $f(n)$ over $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to know its maximum value over a very large domain, say $n=1,2,3,4,...,10^6$. Is there a way to ask Mathematica to give me the maximum value of this function?

```
f [n_]:= Abs[(8 (-1)^(-2 n) ((11 + 5 Sqrt[5]) Cos[(4 n π)/(
       1 + Sqrt[5])] + (7 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[(4 n π)/(
       3 + Sqrt[5])] + (7 + 3 Sqrt[5]) π Sin[(4 n π)/(
       1 + Sqrt[5])] + (3 + Sqrt[5]) π Sin[(4 n π)/(
       3 + Sqrt[5])]))/(
  n π^3 (-(2 + Sqrt[5]) Sin[2 n π] + 
     Sin[2 (-2 + Sqrt[5]) n π])^2)]/n;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NMaximize[{f[n], 1 <= n <= 10^6, n ∈ Integers}, n]

(* Out: {63.041, {n -> 2}} *)
```

You can then get the corresponding symbolic function value using your definition of `f[n]`:

```
f[2] // FullSimplify
```

[image: symbolic value of f[2]]

Comment: It might be worth noting that `NMaximize` is not guaranteed to return the maximum.

Comment: @charmin How do you know `f[2]` is not the global maximum?  `NMaximize` tries to find the global maximum and it might be succeeding (or might not).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, but actually, I am working with a different function, but does it matter?

Comment: @MichaelE2 It seems that it works with this function, but does not work for the other function I have.

Comment: @charmin Yes, I think it matters whether the first local maximum is in fact the global maximum. -- So you need to ask another question?

Comment: @charmin Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no automatic and general approach to non-linear optimization that guarantees to find the global maximum.

Comment: @MarcoB — well, there is such an approach for integers over a finite domain:  exhaustive search.  See  [Michael E2's answer.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237005/27813)

Answer (score 4):

Exhaustive search is a reasonable method on a small set:

```
vals = f[N[Range[10^6], 16]]; // AbsoluteTiming
Position[vals, #] -> # &@Max[vals]
(*
  {60.0485, Null}
  {{2}} -> 63.04102181896
*)
```

Confirm `f[2]` is the max (with arbitrary-precision, we get evidence that round-off error has not messed up the search):

```
Nearest[vals, Max[vals], 2]
(*  {63.04102181896, 56.03221153}  *)

MinMax[Precision /@ vals]
(* {3.15971, 14.2151}  <-- results have > 3 digits precision *)
```

If you're sure round-off is no problem, machine-precision is faster:

```
vals = f[N[Range[10^6]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
Position[vals, #] -> # &@Max[vals]
(*
  {1.60528, Null}
  {{2}} -> 63.041
*)
```

Also, using `Simplify[f[n], n \[Element] Integers]` is 30-35% faster in this case, but that's because `f[n]` happens to contain terms like `Sin[2 n \[Pi]]`.

Comment: @charmin Don't change the question after it has been answered! If the approach Michael and I have proposed does not work for that new function, then ask a different question.

Comment: @MarcoB I did not mean to change the question, since I could not write my function in the comment, I wrote in the question, then I wanted to remove it.

Comment: Note that depending on the function, you may need to apply `Chop` or `Re` to eliminate small imaginary parts that arise in the calculation (`(-1)^100000.` is not quite real according to Mathematica.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks, I forgot that. With arbitrary-precision inputs, the round-off error bounds on the imaginary parts are normally greater than the round-off error bounds, and one can be more rigorous than `Chop` or `Re`: E.g. `vals /. z_ /; Im@z == 0 :> Re[z]`. OTOH, an imaginary part might indicate that the input was not in the domain: E.g., ``Log[x] - Log[x + 1] /. x -> -2.`16``, which `Chop` or `Re` or my fix would cover up.  Perhaps a check like ``VectorQ[vals, Developer`RealQ]`` should precede finding `Max[vals]`.